# Android: No files appearing in File Explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I found out that I couldn't view my Android database files in Eclipse without rooting my phone, so I ended up rooting my Samsung Galaxy SII using the directions here:

http://galaxys2root.com/galaxy-s2-root/how-to-root-ics-on-att-galaxy-s2-sgh-i777/

Now when I use the adb shell, I'm able to view all the databases in my /data/data/... folder.  But in Eclipse, when I open DDMS and view the File Explorer, I don't see any files.  I made sure I selected my device in the "Device" window.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

**Edit:** If someone could point me in the right direction for rooting a Samsung Galaxy S II that will still work with Eclipse, please let me know...I spent hours just getting my phone rooted since things like "simple" one click did not work for me.

Comment: If this is why you rooted and your app is not a game/file-system heavy app, I would've recommended using an emulator instead.

Comment: Even the same happened for me as well, just did adb devices and the adb server was down. Just did `kill-server` and `start-server`, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to see the database files while running an Emulator

There's a neat little plugin for Eclipse called [CellObject SQLite Browser](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cellobject-sqlite-xml-browser#.UQQ00Wfw6RM)  that allows you to view the sqlite database and it's contents(not modify). Try launching an emulator and then navigating to the File Explorer tab, find your app's package name, data folder, and open the db file by clicking the plugin icon(it will automatically include an icon right next to the DDMS option)