# Android Studios: Android Device Manager shows no files for Nougat 7.0 in File Explorer

Tags: android, sqlite, shell

I'm learning how to integrate databases (SQLite) into my app.

I checked out this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/p8TaTgr4uKM?t=10m) and at the 10m mark, OP enters the FileExplorer in Android Device Manager in Android Studio.

Can't see ANY files in the File Explorer. **Using the File Explorer is the desired result.** Last Night, I've Rooted my Nexus 6p (7.0) and reinstalled Studio 2.2.2 after reading these stackoverflow dialogues with no desired result, the issue has a long history:

1)  [Android Device Monitor "data" folder is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603355/android-device-monitor-data-folder-is-empty)
[How to Find my App's /data/data using Android Device Monitor's File Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616985/how-to-find-my-apps-data-data-using-android-device-monitors-file-explorer)

-Rooted phone (6p) doesn't show any files in FileExplorer (Verfied with Root Checker)
-Emulator doesn't show anything in FileExplorer

2)  [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device)
[How do I view the SQLite database on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-do-i-view-the-sqlite-database-on-an-android-device)
[SQLite database cannot be accessed although device is rooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561661/sqlite-database-cannot-be-accessed-although-device-is-rooted)
[Android Studio - Android Device Monitor's File explorer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275988/android-studio-android-device-monitors-file-explorer-not-working)
[Android: No files appearing in File Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542914/android-no-files-appearing-in-file-explorer)

a) adb shell
run-as com.your.packagename
*Has corrupt installation - maybe it's me*

b) adb shell
su
chmod /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.package
*bad mode '/data'

Nothing, doesn't show any files in FileExplorer*

c) adb shell
su
chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/
*Nothing, doesn't show any files in FileExplorer*

d) adb shell
su
chmod -R 777 data/
*Nothing, doesn't show any files in FileExplorer*

3)  [How can I see the contents of a sqlite db of my app in a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155495/how-can-i-see-the-contents-of-a-sqlite-db-of-my-app-in-a-real-device/)
*Nothing, doesn't show any files in FileExplorer*

4)  http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/help/android-device-manager-7-0-nougat-t3454419
    Maybe it's not just me, and something is wrong with Nougat 7.0, but there seems to be a continuous stream of the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm tempted to restart my application and try IntelliJ or Eclipse but I'm not sure if that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with me (good sign of validation) but [a problem with the emulators targeting Android 24 or 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669552/ddms-showing-empty-file-explorer-for-online-emulator).

Issue re-reported back in Oct '16:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225049. Faith that Google will resolve this issue as soon as possible.

For now, **the solution is to run your emulator using API 23** and there should be no problem accessing the File Explorer with the data using Android Device Manager.

*Hurray!*

Comment: Was it fixed in API 26?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the solution to your question is No Solution till date.

This is a bug which many android developers had raised.

1.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229628

2.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225049

3.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226984

So if anybody is facing this issue, use emulators targeting Android 23 or its previous versions..

Answer (score 0):

A new tool window has been added to Android Studio 2.4 (currently in canary) that will allow you to interact with API 24 devices and emulators directly in Android Studio. Once you have updated to 2.4 canary, you can find the tool window in View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer.