# Device manager file manager is Empty for Nougat emulator

Tags: android, ddms

In my PC file manager of ddms is working fine, it's showing all the folder from devices, but for emulator which is working on Lollipop or below version, but for Nougat version file manager doesn't showing any data, it's always empty for Nougat emulator.

Comment: I have the same problem in Windows 7 :(  Let us know should you find any solutions...

Comment: also found another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118255/android-studios-android-device-manager-shows-no-files-for-nougat-7-0-in-file-ex.  Based on that thread it seems like a Android bug...

Comment: Found the probelm..earlier sources for api 23  was not available in sdk manager , so it was not showing the any data in file exploper. Now after downloading sources its working fine.